# get the first value and refrech data without reload page Angular Select

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

first problem i need to get def[image]ault value in the select

second when i choose the first select i get the data in the select two but when i change again the select one the data went missing and need reload to get them again
[image]

[image]

**my html code is :**

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Morceau">Artiste <span style="color: red;">*</span> </label>
          <select #mySelect (change)="onMakeChange( mySelect.value)" [(ngModel)]="suggestion.artiste_id"
            name="artiste_id" type="text" class="form-control  z-depth-1" id="Morceau" style=" border-style: solid;
              border-width: 3px; border-color:#000">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let artiste of artistes" value="{{artiste?._id}}">{{artiste?.artiste_name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="Artiste">Morceau <span style="color: red;">*</span> </label>
          <select type="text" class="form-control  z-depth-1" id="Artiste" style=" border-style: solid;
              border-width: 3px; border-color:#000" [(ngModel)]="suggestion.lyrics_id" name="lyrics_id">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let lyrics of lyrics" value="{{lyrics?._id}}">{{lyrics?.titleOfLyrics}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

**my code ts is :**

 artistes: any[] = [];
  lyrics: any[] = [];
  suggestion: any = {
    artiste_id: "",
    lyrics_id: "",
    email: "",
    punchline: "",
  };
getAllArtiste() {
    this.artisteSRV.getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.artistes = data;
      console.log("artistes", data);
    });
  }
  getAllLyrics() {
    this.lyricsSRV.getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.lyrics = data;
      console.log("lyrics", data);
    });
  }
  onMakeChange($event) {
    if (this.suggestion.artiste_id)
      var selectedLyrics = this.lyrics.filter(
        (art) => art.artiste._id == this.suggestion.artiste_id
      );
    this.lyrics = selectedLyrics;
    delete this.suggestion.lyrics_id;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.lyrics` is originally set to your full list of all lyrics.

This line:

`this.lyrics = selectedLyrics;`

Is assigning the filtered set of lyrics to your list of *all* lyrics.

Then when the user picks another artist,

`var selectedLyrics = this.lyrics.filter(...)`

You are filtering that already filtered list.

You need to have two different variables:

- One for the full list of lyrics. This will always hold all of the lyrics and will be the full list that is then filtered into another variable.
- One for the filtered list which is bound to the drop down.

**Sample code**

```
export class MyComponent {
  artistes: Artist[] = [];
  lyrics: Lyrics[] = [];
  suggestion: any = {
        artiste_id: '',
        lyrics_id: '',
        email: '',
        punchline: ''
  };
  unfilteredLyrics: Lyrics[] = []; // <-- I ADDED THIS

  constructor() {
    this.getAllArtiste();
    this.getAllLyrics();
  }

  getAllArtiste() {
    this.artisteSRV_getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.artistes = data;
      console.log('artistes', data);
    });
  }
  getAllLyrics() {
    this.lyricsSRV_getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
      // Set the full list of unfiltered lyrics
      this.unfilteredLyrics = data; // <-- I ADDED THIS
      this.lyrics = data;
      console.log('lyrics', data);
    });
  }
  onMakeChange($event) {
    if (this.suggestion.artiste_id)
      // Always start the filtering from the unfiltered list
      // I CHANGED THE VARIABLE BELOW
      var selectedLyrics = this.unfilteredLyrics.filter(
        art => art.artiste._id == this.suggestion.artiste_id
      );
    this.lyrics = selectedLyrics;
    delete this.suggestion.lyrics_id;
  }
}
```

I have a working Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-posts-behavior-subject-procedural-vs-declarative-eoqqcx